# Caption missing from the app when I have input type DOB

Tags: javascript, android, html, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am working on a mobile app which is done in phonegap.

In a sign up form I have a field for Date of birth.

Which I am having like below

```
<input type="date" id="example1" placeholder="DOB">
```

I want to have my input type date because once I generate the apk I get what I want, but When the sign up page comes, It doesn't show the **placeholder** which I wish to show.

I am not sure how I can get this done. I tried with `value = "dd/mm/yyyy"` but doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can play trick by using onfocus and onblur.

```
<input placeholder="DOB" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" id="example1" >
```

[image: DOB]

[image: after clicking on field]

Comment: I have tested it on my Cordova/PhoneGap app and it works fine.

Comment: I have added screenshots. You can tell me the device you are testing on and also the Cordova version.